# How to split the given email address into different parts in php

Tags: php

I want to know that how I can split the address `saeed000@vu.edu.pk` by using different functions of PHP, in the result I want to display it like:

```
username = saeed000
domainname = vu
domain type = education
and he is from Pakistan.
```

Comment: You can use the `explode` function twice - once to split "before `@`" from "after `@`", then again to split the second half into components. Of course there is no guarantee that an email address will have three components after the `@`, so how to parse that further is a very tricky problem unless you have constraints. How would you want to parse `john.smith@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 7):

I would do

```
<?php
    $email = 'saeed000@vu.edu.pk';
    $a1 = explode("@", $email);
    $username = $a1[0];
    $dom = explode(".", $a1[1]);
    print "username = ".$username."\nremaining parts:\n";
    foreach( $dom as $d ) {
      print $d."\n";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
username = saeed000
remaining parts:
vu
edu
pk
```

How you want to interpret the components of the 'remaining' is a tricky problem; there are a great many variations on valid mail addresses, and many times they will not contain any country information. You could of course check for the last element (in the above case `pk`) and check it against a list of known country codes:

```
$countryCodes = array(
  'pk' => 'Pakistan',
  'nl' => 'Netherlands',
  'us' => 'USA');

if(array_key_exists($d, $countryCodes)) {
  print "The user is from ".$countryCodes[$d]."\n";
}
else print "The TLD code $d was not found\n";
```

Obviously you would have to create a complete array `$countryCodes` - I am just showing a very small example. The complete list of country codes is below. (parsed from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). I can't guarantee that some error didn't creep in, but this should be close. If you copy this into a standalone file and call it `countryCodes.php`, then add the line

```
include "countryCodes.php"
```

in your main routine, (instead of the inline definition of the array that is there now) you will have the complete lookup table available.

```
<?php
$countryCodes = Array(
"ac" => "Ascension Island",
"ad" => "Andorra",
"ae" => "United Arab Emirates",
"af" => "Afghanistan",
"ag" => "Antigua and Barbuda",
"ai" => "Anguilla",
"al" => "Albania",
"am" => "Armenia",
"an" => "Netherlands Antilles",
"ao" => "Angola",
"aq" => "Antarctica",
"ar" => "Argentina",
"as" => "American Samoa",
"at" => "Austria",
"au" => "Australia",
"aw" => "Aruba",
"ax" => "Åland",
"az" => "Azerbaijan",
"ba" => "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
"bb" => "Barbados",
"bd" => "Bangladesh",
"be" => "Belgium",
"bf" => "Burkina Faso",
"bg" => "Bulgaria",
"bh" => "Bahrain",
"bi" => "Burundi",
"bj" => "Benin",
"bm" => "Bermuda",
"bn" => "Brunei",
"bo" => "Bolivia",
"br" => "Brazil",
"bs" => "Bahamas",
"bt" => "Bhutan",
"bv" => "Bouvet Island",
"bw" => "Botswana",
"by" => "Belarus",
"bz" => "Belize",
"ca" => "Canada",
"cc" => "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
"cd" => "Democratic Republic of the Congo",
"cf" => "Central African Republic",
"cg" => "Republic of the Congo",
"ch" => "Switzerland",
"ci" => "Côte d'Ivoire",
"ck" => "Cook Islands",
"cl" => "Chile",
"cm" => "Cameroon",
"cn" => "People's Republic of China",
"co" => "Colombia",
"cr" => "Costa Rica",
"cs" => "Czechoslovakia",
"cu" => "Cuba",
"cv" => "Cape Verde",
"cx" => "Christmas Island",
"cy" => "Cyprus",
"cz" => "Czech Republic",
"dd" => "East Germany",
"de" => "Germany",
"dj" => "Djibouti",
"dk" => "Denmark",
"dm" => "Dominica",
"do" => "Dominican Republic",
"dz" => "Algeria",
"ec" => "Ecuador",
"ee" => "Estonia",
"eg" => "Egypt",
"eh" => "Western Sahara",
"er" => "Eritrea",
"es" => "Spain",
"et" => "Ethiopia",
"eu" => "European Union",
"fi" => "Finland",
"fj" => "Fiji",
"fk" => "Falkland Islands",
"fm" => "Federated States of Micronesia",
"fo" => "Faroe Islands",
"fr" => "France",
"ga" => "Gabon",
"gb" => "United Kingdom",
"gd" => "Grenada",
"ge" => "Georgia",
"gf" => "French Guiana",
"gg" => "Guernsey",
"gh" => "Ghana",
"gi" => "Gibraltar",
"gl" => "Greenland",
"gm" => "The Gambia",
"gn" => "Guinea",
"gp" => "Guadeloupe",
"gq" => "Equatorial Guinea",
"gr" => "Greece",
"gs" => "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
"gt" => "Guatemala",
"gu" => "Guam",
"gw" => "Guinea-Bissau",
"gy" => "Guyana",
"hk" => "Hong Kong",
"hm" => "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
"hn" => "Honduras",
"hr" => "Croatia",
"ht" => "Haiti",
"hu" => "Hungary",
"id" => "Indonesia",
"ie" => "Ireland",
"il" => "Israel",
"im" => "Isle of Man",
"in" => "India",
"io" => "British Indian Ocean Territory",
"iq" => "Iraq",
"ir" => "Iran",
"is" => "Iceland",
"it" => "Italy",
"je" => "Jersey",
"jm" => "Jamaica",
"jo" => "Jordan",
"jp" => "Japan",
"ke" => "Kenya",
"kg" => "Kyrgyzstan",
"kh" => "Cambodia",
"ki" => "Kiribati",
"km" => "Comoros",
"kn" => "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
"kp" => "Democratic People's Republic of Korea",
"kr" => "Republic of Korea",
"kw" => "Kuwait",
"ky" => "Cayman Islands",
"kz" => "Kazakhstan",
"la" => "Laos",
"lb" => "Lebanon",
"lc" => "Saint Lucia",
"li" => "Liechtenstein",
"lk" => "Sri Lanka",
"lr" => "Liberia",
"ls" => "Lesotho",
"lt" => "Lithuania",
"lu" => "Luxembourg",
"lv" => "Latvia",
"ly" => "Libya",
"ma" => "Morocco",
"mc" => "Monaco",
"md" => "Moldova",
"me" => "Montenegro",
"mg" => "Madagascar",
"mh" => "Marshall Islands",
"mk" => "Macedonia",
"ml" => "Mali",
"mm" => "Myanmar",
"mn" => "Mongolia",
"mo" => "Macau",
"mp" => "Northern Mariana Islands",
"mq" => "Martinique",
"mr" => "Mauritania",
"ms" => "Montserrat",
"mt" => "Malta",
"mu" => "Mauritius",
"mv" => "Maldives",
"mw" => "Malawi",
"mx" => "Mexico",
"my" => "Malaysia",
"mz" => "Mozambique",
"na" => "Namibia",
"nc" => "New Caledonia",
"ne" => "Niger",
"nf" => "Norfolk Island",
"ng" => "Nigeria",
"ni" => "Nicaragua",
"nl" => "Netherlands",
"no" => "Norway",
"np" => "Nepal",
"nr" => "Nauru",
"nu" => "Niue",
"nz" => "New Zealand",
"om" => "Oman",
"pa" => "Panama",
"pe" => "Peru",
"pf" => "French Polynesia",
"pg" => "Papua New Guinea",
"ph" => "Philippines",
"pk" => "Pakistan",
"pl" => "Poland",
"pm" => "Saint-Pierre and Miquelon",
"pn" => "Pitcairn Islands",
"pr" => "Puerto Rico",
"ps" => "State of Palestine",
"pt" => "Portugal",
"pw" => "Palau",
"py" => "Paraguay",
"qa" => "Qatar",
"re" => "Réunion",
"ro" => "Romania",
"rs" => "Serbia",
"ru" => "Russia",
"rw" => "Rwanda",
"sa" => "Saudi Arabia",
"sb" => "Solomon Islands",
"sc" => "Seychelles",
"sd" => "Sudan",
"se" => "Sweden",
"sg" => "Singapore",
"sh" => "Saint Helena",
"si" => "Slovenia",
"sj" => "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands  ",
"sk" => "Slovakia",
"sl" => "Sierra Leone",
"sm" => "San Marino",
"sn" => "Senegal",
"so" => "Somalia",
"sr" => "Suriname",
"ss" => "South Sudan",
"st" => "São Tomé and Príncipe",
"su" => "Soviet Union",
"sv" => "El Salvador",
"sx" => "Sint Maarten",
"sy" => "Syria",
"sz" => "Swaziland",
"tc" => "Turks and Caicos Islands",
"td" => "Chad",
"tf" => "French Southern and Antarctic Lands",
"tg" => "Togo",
"th" => "Thailand",
"tj" => "Tajikistan",
"tk" => "Tokelau",
"tl" => "East Timor",
"tm" => "Turkmenistan",
"tn" => "Tunisia",
"to" => "Tonga",
"tp" => "East Timor",
"tr" => "Turkey",
"tt" => "Trinidad and Tobago",
"tv" => "Tuvalu",
"tw" => "Taiwan",
"tz" => "Tanzania",
"ua" => "Ukraine",
"ug" => "Uganda",
"uk" => "United Kingdom",
"us" => "United States of America",
"uy" => "Uruguay",
"uz" => "Uzbekistan",
"va" => "Vatican City",
"vc" => "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
"ve" => "Venezuela",
"vg" => "British Virgin Islands",
"vi" => "United States Virgin Islands",
"vn" => "Vietnam",
"vu" => "Vanuatu",
"wf" => "Wallis and Futuna",
"ws" => "Samoa",
"ye" => "Yemen",
"yt" => "Mayotte",
"yu" => "Yugoslavia",
"za" => "South Africa",
"zm" => "Zambia",
"zw" => "Zimbabwe");
?>
```

Comment: All domain names will have _at least_ two parts, separated by .'s. There is no fixed pattern for the pieces -- the TLD (top level domain) could be one (e.g., .com) or (at least) two parts (e.g., edu.pk). The remainder could be a single part (e.g., vu) or could include 1+ subdomain parts (e.g., mail.vu). About the best you can do is to exhaustively match against all known patterns. Note that "commercial" could be something like .com or .co.uk or .com.au. Other than as an academic exercise, what are you trying to do? Is there a limited set of domains or TLDs to deal with?

Comment: @PhilPerry - I agree, this question probably "does not have an answer in its current form". I am hoping that my approach above will give OP at least some ideas on both the complexity of the problem, and ways to tackle parts of it. And it was fun to create the `countryCodes.php` file - might come in handy at some point in the future.